# set dynamic a image form bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have a question. I am new to Android
my program set a image in grid view . get name from list and go to assets folder and show picture. I want show picture from drawable but i cant. my class is extends ArrayAdapter

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    try { BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open(items.get(position).uri));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);       
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i am need get name pic from list and go to drawable and show in imageview
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an Integer array of drawables like this:

```
    private Integer[] drawbleArray = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3};
```

Pass this array to your adapter as a argument in constructor and you can set image like this:

```
imageView.setImageResource(drawbleArray[i]);
```

Comment: thanks. but your code error is:The method setImageDrawable(Drawable) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)

Comment: sorry buddy, I must have done it by mistake. See my updated answer